# show that G is abelian (commuative) group.

Tags: group-theory

If $G=\{\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}:x\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\}$
show that G is abelian (commuative) group.
I have to show "." is a Binary opreation, Associative and commuative.
but as for a Identity element and Inverse, Is this $E=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1/x & 1/x\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ correct answer ?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct answer. It only remains to show the operation is associative and commutative. Hint: If you forget about the matrices and think about the entries of the matrix, it looks a lot like the commutative group $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since matrix multiplication is associative, we only have to show that the multiplication is commutative. This follows from

$$\pmatrix{x&x\\0&0}\pmatrix{y&y\\0&0}=\pmatrix{xy&xy\\0&0}$$

This multiplication also shows that the product of two elements of the set is in the set again.